# Using Arduino LMIC library with EnableInterrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, lora

I am using the [EnableInterrupt](https://github.com/GreyGnome/EnableInterrupt/) library, infact the only library that I can find that allows me to use six interrupts to wake the Arduino. However when I use it with the [LMIC](https://github.com/mcci-catena/arduino-lmic) library (Matthijs Kooijman ) the "Forward uplink data message" is not sent during initial registration, only if
#include <EnableInterrupt.h> is commented out does it work. I am using a RFM95 with the following LMIC pin assignments:

const lmic_pinmap lmic_pins = {
.nss = 10,
.rxtx = LMIC_UNUSED_PIN,
.rst = 9,
.dio = {3, 8, LMIC_UNUSED_PIN},
};

This must be something to do with the library sharing ISRs.  Could somebody point to which parts of the LMIC library so as not to have this conflict?

I have tried swapping 8 for A5 and it again only works when the line is commented. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work by specifying
#define EI_NOTPORTD however it does not work with  #define EI_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTED_PIN which is needed for my project to function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can get to work with 6 available pin change interrupts - just enough!

```
#define EI_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTED_PIN
#define EI_NOTPORTB  // DISABLE FOR LMIC
#define EI_NOTPORTD  // DISABLE FOR LMIC
```